# Strange behavior with std::map::iterator's postincrement

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

From what I understand, the following program

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int,int> foo;
    std::map<int,int>::iterator start = foo.begin();
    while (start++ != foo.end())
        ;
}
```

should terminate, but it instead loops indefinitely using libstdc++ 4.7.2. Is the behavior exhibited by this program correct, or is there a bug in the standard library? What are the operational properties of operator++(int) on iterators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `map` is empty, so the first `start++` is attempting to increment an `end` iterator which is undefined behaviour. From [`std::map::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end):

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the container.
>   This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.

Even though the post increment `start++` returns the original value of `start`, which in this case would be `end()`, it is unreasonable to expect the loop to terminate due to the presence of undefined behaviour.

To correct, check if `start` is equal to `foo.end()` before incrementing or dereferencing.

Comment: Bonus Question to your answer: So iterators do not have the same behavior than primitives? for int -> i++ returns the old value of i while ++i returns the new value. so start++ should return foo.end() because thats the value before iteration.

Comment: @ChriZzZ, but `start` has still been modified which is undefined behaviour. So expecting the loop to terminate is unreasonable in the presence of undefined behaviour.