# how remove multiple items from multimap in one step of while?

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

I use iterator for removing items, I want to erase first item and second item from my map in each step of while.

Here is code (this code is part of Huffman code)

```
std::multimap<float, node *> ::iterator first, second;
first = floattnode.begin();
second = ++first;
while (floattnode.size() != 0) { //floattnode is a multimap mapping frequency to node
    root = new node((*first).first + (*second).first, '-');
    root->left = new node(((*first).second), 0);
    root->right = new node(((*second).second), 1);

    floattnode.erase(first);
    floattnode.erase(second);//here i have problem

    first = floattnode.begin(); //check
    floattnode.insert(std::pair<float, node *>(root->freq, root));
    first = floattnode.begin();
    second = ++first;
}
```

when iterator remove first item it can't access to second item to erase, how can I remove this two items ?

Comment: Please provide the declaration of `node`, `root` and `floattnode`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the last block of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
second=++first;
```

Here you are not only assigning the iterator to the second element to `second`, but also you are stepping the iterator in `first`, because `++` is the increment operator, which increments its operand. There seems not to be an addition operator for `multimap` iterators. So you will have to decrease the iterator after you assigned `second` again:

```
second = (++first)++;
```

This will first increment `first` and return it to `second`, after that it will be incremented again. Or assign to `second` and increment it afterwards:

```
second = first;
second++;
```

or shorter:

```
(second = first)++;
```

Anyway you should first check whether there are at least two elements in the container. If there is no element, then `first == floattnode.end()`, which you will try to increment, invoking undefined behaviour. (My setup actually gives me an infinite loop for trying this, see also [Strange behavior with std::map::iterator's postincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718532/strange-behavior-with-stdmapiterators-postincrement))

```
while (floattnode.size() != 0) {
```

You are creating new objects with `new` in each loop turn and assign their pointer to `root`, later you insert pointers to them into `floattnode`, but erase them in one of the later loop turns again. So you loose all references to the created objects at some point. Since you also never call `delete` on them, you are leaking memory there.

Since you add an element to `floattnode` at the end of each loop run, `floattnode.size()` can never be zero at the loop condition check. This is an infinite loop.

```
root=new node((*first).first+(*second).first,'-');
```

If `floattnode.size() == 1` this will be executed and `second` will be dereferenced, although it points behind the last element of the map. This results in undefined behaviour.

Instead of `(*first).first` you should use `first->first` for readability. (It does the same).

```
floattnode.erase(first);
floattnode.erase(second);//here i have problem
```

You are trying to erase the same iterator twice because of the error I mentioned in the beginning. In general iterators to containers may become invalid if the container is modified, so if you want to make sure this doesn't affect you use:

```
floattnode.erase(floattnode.begin());
floattnode.erase(floattnode.begin()); // Notice this is now the originally second element because the first one was erased.
```

However for `multimap` it seems that only the erased iterator is invalidated by calling `erase`, based on the answers here: [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) . Sou you should be fine with your original code in this case.

Because you only check for the container size to be greater than zero, there is again undefined behaviour if the size is exactly `1` and you try to erase the second element (that is `floattnode.end()`, pointing behind the last element).

```
second = ++first;
```

Same error as at the beginning.

Comment: I think Opeartor + isnt defined for Iterator , because of that I use ++ and then -- , for example second=++first and then frist-- , to save first. i will edit my code it was my wrong , but my question is independed of my code ,actully my code was an example

Comment: Thank U I got my answer, but when i write second=first+1 this error comes:"no operator "+" matches operands". I think second=++first means increasing then assigning so second is second Item, am I right ?

Comment: @Nastaran You are right the operator really doesn't exist. It does however for `vector`. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I never modify sets, lists or maps in place. I always create a new one and loop through the old one adding the entries I want into the new one and omit the ones I want to delete.

I tried understanding what was happening with delete in place and iterators and decided it was too hard for me, and anyone coming after me.